# How to call a Firebase observe within a loop?

Tags: json, swift, multithreading, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase JSON structure that has an auto-generated "Party Id" with children from 0-200. As children of these children, I have auto-generated "Song Ids" as the key and vote count as the value. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Firebase JSON]

My issue occurs when I attempt to observe each of these song objects. My code to perform this observe is (removed some extra stuff to simplify the question):

```
    REF_PARTY_VOTING.child(party.partyId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

        allObjects.forEach({ (snap) in
            let options = snap.value as! [String: Any]

            for option in options {

                print()
                print("Outside")
                print(option.key)
                print()

                SongApi().observeSong(withId: option.key, completion: { (song) in

                    print()
                    print("Inside")
                    print(option.key)
                    print()
                })


            }
        })
    }
```

When running this method, the "Outside" print statement prints the values properly. However, the "Inside" print statement seems to be repeating some of the values. Since I am planning to add the song objects to an array, I cannot have objects repeating.

The SongApi observeSong function also uses an observeSingleEvent. This function gets the dictionary from the value of observation and uses it to create a song object. The observeSong function looks like:

```
func observeSong(withId id: String, completion: @escaping (Song) -> Void) {
    REF_SONGS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let song = Song(songData: dict)
            completion(song)
        }
    })
}
```

I originally thought that the issue could potentially be solved using DispatchGroup since the observeSong function is only being called after all the "Outside" prints have been printed; however, that has not solved the problem either. Do you know why this is happening and what could fix the problem?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Its been a while since I used firebase, but it seems to me that maybe your SongApi() isn't observing a single event?  If you could maybe post your API code that would help. Maybe you need a map instead of an array?

Comment: @SamFurlong I have added the API code to the question. Hopefully that can provide some clarity. Also, I do not know much about maps but I will look into them!

Comment: I'm curious if part of the problem may be that the closure is capturing a reference to option.key. If that were the case your print statement might not work as expected in the interior. You might have tried this, but maybe you could increment a counter every time you call SongAPI and then have another counter you increment when Completion is called... if those values match, I would assume this is some issue with swift capturing the reference to Option.key if they aren't the same then there must be an issue firebase/the way you are calling the api.